# Linux: robust way to get Timezone in form Continent/City

Tags: debian, timezone

I'm looking for a portable/robust way to obtain timezone of a Linux box (mainly different versions of Debian) in form of Continent/City, like Europe/Kiev.

Till now I did it using `timedatectl status | grep zone | cut -d' ' -f10`
The problem with this approach is that it works on Debian 9, but not on Debian 10 (can easily be checked using docker images).

Is there a better, more universal/portable way to do this (better without scratching/parsing the output of another command)?
If not, how should I modify the command above, so it works on both Debian 9 and 10.

Comment: SImilar to a question asked 14 hours ago: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/567300/how-can-i-get-a-continent-array-from-a-country-list-in-python

Answer (score 3):

```
timedatectl status | awk '/zone/ {print $3}'
```

Comment: How do you square that with the question saying that it does not work?

Comment: The `... | cut -d' ' -f10` in the question relies on the number of spaces being constant on `timedatectl`'s output, but that changes between Debian 9 and 10. Debian 10's `timedatectl` aligns the fields differently, but the number of words on the line is still the same, so `awk` works where `cut` fails. It would be a better idea to parse the machine-readable output of `timedatectl show` instead - but unfortunately Debian 9 does not seem to have that option available.

Comment: All of that should be explained in the answer.  Think of the poor readers coming to this in the future.

Comment: Lacking time here, but you always can edit my answer and insert the explanation ;-)

Answer (score 3):

The geographic timezone names are both an abstraction and a convenience. Under the hood, the timezone data files are binaries which list offsets, discontinuities and DST changes but not location (even if the filename indicates it, hence the problem with `/etc/localtime`). There is a mapping from location *and date* to timezone offsets, but it's not 1:1 – given the output of `date` for example, you cannot easily and deterministically derive the geographic location in use (but you could compute a set of compatible ones for the current date; or you could, with some effort, inspect earlier dates for discontinuities in order to deduce a location).

There is a [master list of zone names](https://data.iana.org/time-zones/tzdb-2019c/zone.tab), and the timezone definition files [look like](https://data.iana.org/time-zones/tzdb-2019c/europe):

```
# Zone  NAME            GMTOFF  RULES   FORMAT  [UNTIL]
Zone    Europe/London   -0:01:15 -      LMT     1847 Dec  1 0:00s
                         0:00   GB-Eire %s      1968 Oct 27
                         1:00   -       BST     1971 Oct 31 2:00u
                         0:00   GB-Eire %s      1996
                         0:00   EU      GMT/BST
Link    Europe/London   Europe/Jersey
Link    Europe/London   Europe/Guernsey
Link    Europe/London   Europe/Isle_of_Man
```

When creating the binary `Europe/London` file the indicated rules are processed to build the time rules (the timestamps where something changes, inspect with `zdump -v Europe/London`), and the related locations are aliased. The  `localtime` file contents or `date` output from any of the above locations will be indistinguishable.

The abstraction lets you handle legal changes in time, such as

```
# TZ=Europe/Andorra date -d "Aug 31 1984"
Fri Aug 31 00:00:00 CET 1984

TZ=Europe/Andorra date -d "Aug 31 1985"
Sat Aug 31 00:00:00 CEST 1985
```

(Andorra is not in the EU, but follows EU DST rules since 1985)

`/etc/localtime` is the (binary) timezone data file, on Debian by convention it should be a symlink to the named geographic timezone file according to the [''Stretch''](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/systemd/localtime.5.en.html) (9) and [''Buster''](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/systemd/localtime.5.en.html) (10) `localtime` man pages:

> The /etc/localtime file configures the system-wide timezone of the local 
>   system that is used by applications for presentation to the user. It 
>   should be an absolute or relative symbolic link pointing to /usr/share
>   /zoneinfo/, followed by a timezone identifier such as "Europe/Berlin" or 
>   "Etc/UTC". The resulting link should lead to the corresponding binary tzfile(5)
>   timezone data for the configured timezone.
>
> Because the timezone identifier is extracted from the symlink target name of 
>   /etc/localtime, this file may not be a normal file or hardlink.

Assuming that's the case:

```
if [ -L /etc/localtime ]; then
  IFS=/ read -a TZFILE < <(readlink -f /etc/localtime)
  printf -v TZNAME "%s/%s\n" ${TZFILE[-2]} ${TZFILE[-1]}
  echo $TZNAME
fi
```

In earlier versions (or if someone has not been following the documentation) it was a *copy* of the timezone data file. So, to verify that `/etc/localtime` and `/etc/timezone` are in agreement you [need to compare them](https://wiki.debian.org/TimeZoneChanges):

```
$ diff -s /etc/localtime /usr/share/zoneinfo/`cat /etc/timezone`
Files /etc/localtime and /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/New_York are identical
```

If you need to work backwards, or be thorough:

```
read CHECK file < <(sha256sum /etc/localtime)
while read sum file; do 
  [[ "$sum" == "$CHECK" ]] && printf "%s\n" "$file"
done < <(find /usr/share/zoneinfo/ -type f |xargs sha256sum)
```

This isn't a truly portable answer (POSIX doesn't define or require these [long names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database), they come from ICANN/IANA), and you're using `systemd` commands on those versions of Debian.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the timezone from `/etc/timezone` file:

```
cat /etc/timezone
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that the file that actually determines the system default timezone is `/etc/localtime` - and while the OS installer sets both files with the same timezone, a system administrator who's used to older ways of doing things may overwrite `/etc/localtime` without changing `/etc/timezone` to match.

Answer (score 1):

Use tzselect in modern linux servers. 
run tzselect and start drilling down through the prompts.

```
~]# tzselect 
Please identify a location so that time zone rules can be set correctly.
Please select a continent or ocean.
 1) Africa
 2) Americas
 3) Antarctica
 4) Arctic Ocean
 5) Asia
 6) Atlantic Ocean
 7) Australia
 8) Europe
 9) Indian Ocean
10) Pacific Ocean
11) none - I want to specify the time zone using the Posix TZ format.
#?
```

Sorry I just re-read you orig post. looks like you want a scriptable way to get the time zone. I will leave this in case it helps but prob not what you needed.

Answer (score 0):

This works great across both Unix and Mac machines:

```bash
readlink /etc/localtime | awk -F'/' '{print $(NF-1)"/"$(NF)}'
```